# How to compare the data in two excel sheets using data provider in Selenium

Tags: selenium, testng-dataprovider

I am already having data in excel sheet . New excel sheet will be downloaded on running the selenium script .I need to compare these two excel sheets .

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to compare the excel files in selenium :

- Use **hashmaps** : For this you need to have to have the data inside your excel files in the form or Key-Value pairs. Comparing data in the hashmaps will be easier and more convenient way.

Here is the code snippet for extracting data from excel file to your hashmap (if you are using **Java**) :

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(excelDataString);
    if(null != jsonObject){
        Set<String> keys = jsonObject.keySet();
        for(String key : keys){
            try{
                map.put(key, jsonObject.getString(key));
            } catch(Exception e){
                map.put(key, jsonObject.getString(key).toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

- Use **Apache POI, Fillo** or any other library to read the data from both the excel files and compare them based on the structure of data inside them.